# How to retain the browser URL in angular

Tags: angularjs

Here is the current situation i am having.
 We are exposing the following url to our customers

http://domain/abc/services/dashboard

1. When this happens the user is first redirected to company SSO login automatically and after successful authentication it redirect back to above URL.

   2. dashboards is REST endpoint which we have configured.
   3. After further validations we want to redirect the user to index.html page from where the angular will kick start.

In my jersey end point i am doing sth like this

```
URI contextPath = UriUtils.getFullServletContextPath(servletContext, uriInfo);
 UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(contextPath);
 uriBuilder.path("index.html");
 return Response.seeOther(uriBuilder.build()).build();
```

now in the browser i am seeing http;//domain/abc/index.html and my angular page is loaded perfectly fine.
Now my question was is this the correct approach because i want to retain the URL
which user has clicked initially.

Should i go to rest end point first and then load angular or should i first load angular and from within angular i should invoke the rest endpoint. This endpoint is where the user context will be created.

WHat is the correct way of doing it?